# mdframed frametitle no page break

Tags: mdframed

How can one prevent the frame title from breaking? I'm getting a break right between the title and the contents which looks silly.

I still want the content to be broken as normal but I want the frame title to be on the same page as the content.

Comment: Use the option `needspace`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel That doesn't do anything. I used `\begin{mdframed}[needspace,...]` and there is still a page break between the frametitle and content.

Comment: The option `needspace` requires a length.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Is there any way to add an option to prevent frametitle breaks similar to the nobreak option? Needspace doesn't seem to work in my case because I have to give it a very large number(around 5cm) which may cause other problems(such as not breaking the content at all or having large extra header space). Basically there is no way to explicitly set the value by hard coding it since it changes and it would be easier to simply do a check on the break in the first place.

Comment: At the moment Im must answer with no. I will add such an option.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Thanks. Remember that it should "push" the frame to the next page though instead of keeping it on the same page... else you'll loose virtually all of the content ;)